# No Database selected error in PHP with MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have to select data from MySQL Database. I have been looking for the answer, but still haven't found any. I am learning from [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

My MySQL doesn't have any username or password, so my code looks like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbName = "db_Test";

//Create Connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbName);
//Check Connection
if(!$conn){
    die("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Category, Description, Price FROM items";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(!$result){
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
}

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "ID: ".$row['ID']." Name: ".$row['Name']." Category: ".$row['Category']."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

First I got this error

> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

On further tracing it back in the stack, I got this:

> No database selected

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. So can you explain it to me and give me the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to add username and password for connect mysql database.

for your reference: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: you forgot a password in your mysqli_connect

Comment: As I said to you, My database dont have any username or password. And for your noted, I have succsessfully connection with that code

Answer (score 1):

Set mysql username and passwork something like this.

```
$username = "root";
$password = "";
```

And set connection like this.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```